# how to obtain the window handle of a Choose Color Dialog

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have edited the question Mr Remy. Thanks for your interest

I have a menu item that invokes a ChooseColor dialog successfully. I need to be able to obtain the window handle to Choose Color dialog so as to prevent multiple invocations when the menu item is selected. The menu item simply calls a function called Colors(). Please I only program in C/API.

```
void Colors()
{
    //CHOOSECOLOR CC; CC ia now a global variable
    DWORD rgbOld;
    BOOL retval;
    static DWORD argbCust[16];
    HCURSOR newCursor; 

    newCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    EnableCursor(ghwndBitmap, newCursor);

    ZeroMemory(&CC, sizeof(CHOOSECOLOR));
    CC.lStructSize = sizeof(CHOOSECOLOR);
    CC.hwndOwner =  ghwnd;
    CC.hInstance = (HINSTANCE) ghInstance;
    CC.rgbResult = eraserColor;
    CC.lpCustColors = argbCust;
    CC.Flags = CC_RGBINIT | CC_SHOWHELP | CC_FULLOPEN;
    CC.lCustData = 0;
    CC.lpfnHook = NULL;
    CC.lpTemplateName = NULL;

    if(!chColDlgOn) { //chColDlgOn is a global BOOL variable originally set to FALSE
       retval = ChooseColor(&CC);
       chColDlgOn = TRUE;
    }
    else {
       MessageBeep(0xFFFFFFFF);
       return;
    }
     
    if((retval) && (eraserColor != CC.rgbResult)) {
       eraserColor = CC.rgbResult;
       chColDlgOn = FALSE;
       ShowChosenColor();
    }
    if(currentTool == TOOL_ERASER) {
       if(shapeSize == 0) 
          GetEraserBitmap(currentID, currentShape);
       else
          GetCustomEraserBitmap(ghwndBitmap);
    }
    else 
      currentTool = 0;
    lastColor = eraserColor;
}
```

Comment: "*I need to be able to obtain the [dialog window handle] so as to prevent multiple invocations when the menu item is selected*" - this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) to me. Why are you getting multiple invocations? `ChooseColor()` blocks your code until it exits. If you really are getting overlapping invocations, why not use your own `bool` variable to gate the `ChooseColor()` call? Why do you need the dialog's `HWND` specifically? FYI, the only way to get the `HWND` is to use `CHOOSECOLOR::lpfnHook`, or a `SetWindowsHookEx()` hook like `WH_CBT`.

Comment: 'why not use your own bool variable to gate the ChooseColor() call'. Please how would you express this in plain C/API? Thanks

Comment: really? Declare a global/static `bool` variable set to `false` initially. When you want to call `ChooseColor()`, check the variable first. If it is `true`,  skip the call. If it is `false`, set it to `true`, do the call, then set it to `false`. Done

Comment: Sir Remy, I tried your suggestion but it still didn't work. Below is my source code                             ```

Comment: do not post the code in a comment. Please [edit] your question to add more detail