# How do I prevent multiple invocations of the ChooseColor dialog

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have a Windows application written in C/API. There is a menu item that calls a function called Colors (), which invokes the ChooseColor dialog. How can I prevent multiple invocations of the ChooseColor dialog from the menu as implemented in MS Paint?

```
void Colors()
{
    //CHOOSECOLOR CC; CC is now a global variable
    DWORD rgbOld;
    BOOL retval;
    static DWORD argbCust[16];
    HCURSOR newCursor; 

    newCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    EnableCursor(ghwndBitmap, newCursor);

    ZeroMemory(&CC, sizeof(CHOOSECOLOR));
    CC.lStructSize = sizeof(CHOOSECOLOR);
    CC.hwndOwner =  ghwnd;
    CC.hInstance = (HINSTANCE) ghInstance;
    CC.rgbResult = eraserColor;
    CC.lpCustColors = argbCust;
    CC.Flags = CC_RGBINIT | CC_SHOWHELP | CC_FULLOPEN;
    CC.lCustData = 0;
    CC.lpfnHook = NULL;
    CC.lpTemplateName = NULL;

    if(!chColDlgOn) { //chColDlgOn is a global BOOL variable originally set to FALSE
       retval = ChooseColor(&CC);
       chColDlgOn = TRUE;
    }
    else {
       MessageBeep(0xFFFFFFFF);
       return;
    }
     
    if((retval) && (eraserColor != CC.rgbResult)) {
       eraserColor = CC.rgbResult;
       chColDlgOn = FALSE;
       ShowChosenColor();
    }
    if(currentTool == TOOL_ERASER) {
       if(shapeSize == 0) 
          GetEraserBitmap(currentID, currentShape);
       else
          GetCustomEraserBitmap(ghwndBitmap);
    }
    else 
      currentTool = 0;
    lastColor = eraserColor;
}
```

Comment: Add static flag

Comment: Have the menu entry merely change the visibility of the dialog (as opposed to actually creating it). Calling `ShowWindow` with `SW_SHOW` on a visible window is a no-op. You can get to the window handle by using a [`CCHookProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nc-commdlg-lpcchookproc).

Comment: Paint uses a modal dialog. And you just asked this question a couple of days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73409623/how-to-obtain-the-window-handle-of-a-choose-color-dialog

Comment: You mean Paint does not use the standard ChooseColor dialog, but a custom made one? I think I might have to hack something like that. Thank you Anders

Comment: As far as I tested, [ChooseColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-common-dialog-boxes?redirectedfrom=MSDN#choosing-a-color) Creates a modal dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

`CC.hwndOwner` needs to be set to the HWND of the window/dialog that displays the menu. `ChooseColor` will then be [modal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050224-00/?p=36373) on top of this window.

Comment: You all are right; there was a bug. Apart from the menu bar, I created another toolwindow  with buttons for the various tools of the application. And I was testing with the buttons in the toolwindow while CC.hwndOwner was set to the main window. Sorry to bother you all, but you all helped